# install Phalconphp source file in windows

Tags: php, frameworks, phalcon

I have an experienced in other framework where you need to download the zip file from their website extract it on your root folder and there you go you can start the development. but where can i find the zip file for this framework? by the way i am done installing the proper dynamic link library for this framework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Phalcon is a PHP framework but it is different. It's written in C and compiled as PHP extension (like PDO for example). So you should:

1. Download DLL for Windows [here](http://phalconphp.com/en/download/windows) and put it into your extensions directory
2. Enable it in your php.ini file
3. Restart your web server
4. Create some file with phpinfo() to check phalcon extension
5. Phalcon classes and functions will be available in your code now

**P.S**. You don't need any 'zip files' just enable Phalcon extension and start to develop.

Comment: Oh i see. Its not like other framework where there are zip files to be downloaded and to be used for the development?

Answer (score 0):

There is no such thing like in other PHP frameworks since it's an extension for PHP. It has no PHP files to be downloaded.

If I understand correctly you have installed PhalconPHP extension [from download page](http://phalconphp.com/en/download/windows) in your PHP environment.

The sources of this framework are in C/C++ (1.x versions) or in new language called Zephir (2.x+). They are [available on github](https://github.com/phalcon/cphalcon).

You can browse Phalcon API in [docs](http://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/index.html) or by browsing latest [IDE stubs](https://github.com/phalcon/phalcon-devtools/tree/master/ide/1.3.2) from [Phalcon Devtools project](https://github.com/phalcon/phalcon-devtools). As you can see there are empty methods (hence stubs name) but you can use them in your IDE for code completion.